# "The entry is a door" in Solaris "ls" man page

Tags: solaris, ls, man, door

I found this in a man page for `ls` in solaris linux.

http://www.unix.com/man-page/opensolaris/1/ls/

What does it mean when it says:

> `D`  the entry is a door?

Comment: Wikipedia is your friend [Doors_(computing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doors_(computing))  _Doors are an inter-process communication facility for Unix computer systems. They provide a form of procedure call._

Comment: They also allow for a killer interview question for Solaris admins: When is a door not a door? When it's a jar.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A door is a special file in Solaris for bidirectional communication between processes (*IPC*). Doors provide client processes with a way to call remote code in a server process and fetch the result.

As @HBrujin stated, [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doors_%28computing%29) is a good entry point to doors (if that makes sense to you).

As explained by `ls` man page, doors are identified by the letter `D` in `ls` output.